# Push notifications using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, push-notification

I hope you can advise me.

I have a Spring Boot API and a mobile app. I have to send push notifications to the users one hour before they have to do something, like a reminder. I have the specific date and time stored in a database.

I've been reading about scheduled tasks but I don't like it at all.

So, what do you think is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I've been reading about scheduled tasks but I don't like it at all.

How else should it work? You need some kind of Scheduler / Timer that triggers your code at the specified time.

You could go for the simplest solution that came to my mind:

```
long delay = ...; // calculate the delay when the code should be executed
Runnable theCodeToExecute = () -> System.out.println("hello world");
new Thread(() -> {
  try {
      Thread.sleep(delay);
      runnable.run();
  }
  catch (Exception e){
      System.err.println(e);
  }
}).start();
```

This of course has several disadvantages: When you restart your app, the scheduled task is gone. And it won't be very efficient when you have hundreds of threads sleeping.

There are of course ways to circumvent this:

Store your timers in a database (or in a file). And remove the entries when you sent the notification. And when your application restarts, you simply read the stored entries and restart the timers.

You could use a Queue (or sorted List) of tasks. And have a single Thread, that looks every N seconds for the next task in the queue. If this task is ready, remove it from the Queue (or List) and execute the code.

---

As an alternative, you can of course use a Framework that already does all of this for you, like for example [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)